# Form submit into new tab AND reload current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, tabs

I guess, I have my mind blocked or something, sorry. I can't find a nicer solution for the following problem:

I am sending a form via POST (data handling via server) and want to open the form in a new tab (a custom url with parameters will be created in the backend) and the URL in the current window should change.

My solution with `setTimeout()`:

```
function formsubmit() {
  $("#formID").submit();
  setTimeout(function(){
   window.open("URL", "_self");
  }, 1);
}
```

In the HTML the function will be called if you click the button or an image. The form has the attribute `target="_blank"`.

Is there any other way to submit a form and get the same output?

Comment: Use `location.href="..."`, not window.open

Comment: thanks @CBroe, location.href looks cleaner than window.open and target itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Use data-remote="true" with jquery ajax

**`data-remote="true"` will submit form asynchronously**

```
 <a id="remote" data-remote="true" data-type="json" href="/project/4/request_access">Request Access</a>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#remote").on("ajax:success", function (e, data, status, xhr) {
        window.open("URL", "_self");
     });
});
```

*I hope my anwer will helpfull for you.*

Comment: thanks @tushar, data-remote is like preventDefault() in JS, prefer JS. So you mean I should trigger the function on success of the ajax call? The complete error handling is made in the backend. Any other solution?